# Different estimates of crossed random factor variance using nlme and lme4

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I want to fit a model with two crossed random factors that also allow heteroscedasticity. Whereas `nlme4` allows non-constant error variance, I was not sure how to fit a model with crossed random effects. Recently I found the example in Pinheiro and Bates (2000), p. 163, that suggest the syntax (I fitted only the random intercept, with the Data set "Assay"):

```
model.nlme <- lme(logDens ~ 1, Assay, 
                  random = pdBlocked(list(pdIdent(~ 1), 
                                          pdIdent(~ sample - 1), 
                                          pdIdent(~ dilut - 1))))
```

, which gives the output

```
> model.nlme
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: Assay 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: 57.56285
  Fixed: logDens ~ 1 
(Intercept) 
   0.272999 

Random effects:
 Composite Structure: Blocked

 Block 1: (Intercept)
 Formula: ~1 | Block
         (Intercept)
StdDev: 7.369344e-06

 Block 2: samplea, sampleb, samplec, sampled, samplee, samplef
 Formula: ~sample - 1 | Block
 Structure: Multiple of an Identity
           samplea    sampleb    samplec    sampled    samplee    samplef
StdDev: 0.07433785 0.07433785 0.07433785 0.07433785 0.07433785 0.07433785

 Block 3: dilut1, dilut2, dilut3, dilut4, dilut5
 Formula: ~dilut - 1 | Block
 Structure: Multiple of an Identity
           dilut1    dilut2    dilut3    dilut4    dilut5   Residual
StdDev: 0.2642586 0.2642586 0.2642586 0.2642586 0.2642586 0.04745801

Number of Observations: 60
Number of Groups: 2
```

. However, when I fit the model using `lme4`, the result appears to be differet:

```
model.lme4 <- lmer(logDens ~ 1 + (1 | sample) + (1 | dilut), 
                   data = Assay)

> model.lme4
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: logDens ~ 1 + (1 | sample) + (1 | dilut) 
   Data: Assay 
REML criterion at convergence: -140.0874 
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 sample   (Intercept) 0.07252 
 dilut    (Intercept) 0.27908 
 Residual             0.05137 
Number of obs: 60, groups: sample, 6; dilut, 5
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)  
      0.273
```

. The random effect standard deviations, especially the within-level one, is quite different (7.369344e-06 vs. 0.05137).

Question 1: Are the two models equivalent using the setup as above?

Question 2: If yes, why do they have different results?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the two models are equivalent.  Can you be a little bit more specific about what you mean by "two crossed factors that also allow heteroscedasticity" (e.g. write out explicit mathematical formulas for the statistical model you have in mind)? (Note that the `lme` output for `dilut` includes a residual error term which is not too far off from the `lme4` residual error estimate ...)

Comment: Hi @BenBolker, thanks for your reply. I wanted to have a model for heteroscedasticity, but the codes I gave did not need that. The model would be

$$\text{logDens}_{i(j_1, j_2)} = \gamma_{000} + u_{0j_1} + v_{0j_2} + e_{i(j_1, j_2)},$$

where $u_{0j_1}$, $v_{0j_2}$, and $e_{i(j_1, j_2)}$ are independent normal, and are random effects (or residual terms) of, `sample` level, and `dilut` level, and within-level. Thanks again!